# `usort` not sorting array elements as intended

Tags: php, sorting, usort

I am using `usort` to sort an array based on the number on the value of `sales` key. This is what I have:

Correction: it's not a problem with 14, but anything above 9.

```
$arr = array(

  "a" => array("sales" => 4),
  "b" => array("sales" => 3),
  "c" => array("sales" => 2),
  "d" => array("sales" => 3),
  "e" => array("sales" => 4),
  "f" => array("sales" => 14),
  "g" => array("sales" => 1)

);

$reverse_arr = $arr;

usort($reverse_arr, 'cmp');

print_r( $reverse_arr );

function cmp($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['sales'], $b['sales']);
}
```

The sorting works for most of the part, but only when a value is `14` it behave strange. The item with 14 sales is placed where it shouldn't be. This is the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sales] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sales] => 14
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sales] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [sales] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [sales] => 3
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [sales] => 4
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [sales] => 4
        )

)
```

Any idea why this is happening and how this can be fixed?

Comment: Because  `strcmp` compares __strings__ and not numbers/integers. `return $a['sales'] <=> $b['sales'];` is enough.

Comment: @u_mulder Such a simple solution, I am not very familiar with the PHP functions and got this whole code from a very popular thread of SO for sorting array elements. Thanks for pointing out the problem!

Comment: @u_mulder Please refrain from posting answers as comments. In this case, you've actually posted a _better_ answer than the one currently on the page, but it can't be upvoted properly or accepted because you posted it as a comment.

Comment: @DeepakKamat Perhaps you can propose an edit to the answer you read the code in to include an example of `<=>` as well as `cmp`, or mention the difference between them.

Comment: Please do not tell me what and where should I write)

Comment: @u_mulder It's a pretty fundamental part of how this site works that answers should go in the box marked "Answer", so that they can be upvoted and accepted. It's not like I'm making up some arbitrary rule just to make you look or feel bad.

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing numbers but using a string comparison function to do it, try this instead

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    //return strcmp($a['sales'], $b['sales']);
    return $a['sales'] <=> $b['sales'];
}
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sales] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sales] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sales] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [sales] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [sales] => 4
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [sales] => 4
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [sales] => 14
        )
```

Comment: Thanks! Another user posted the solution too in the comments, but since you posted this as an answer I will accept this. 

Also, what's the difference between `$a['sales'] <=> $b['sales'];` and `$a['sales'] > $b['sales']` ? Common sense says it checks for greater than / equal to etc, and the latter just checks for greater than, but again PHP is strange.